# Possible to blacklist certain words/phrases?

Tags: 2010, service-application

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a set of words and phrases that cannot be entered as values for anything.

What would be the best way to implement this functionality?  I was exploring creating a Custom Service Application, but I'm having trouble finding information about Custom Service Applications.  Would this be the correct route to take?  Is there a better way to accomplish having blacklisted words?

Comment: is it for *any* data that is entered? so custom lists, listnames, items, pages?

Comment: And do you want to block it realtime, or do you want to moderate it afterwards?

Comment: @Bas, it would just be for list data.  I would like to block it real time, or prompt the user to change it.

Comment: You could write an eventhandler for the lists that you would like to scan, but that would be a bit of a hassle, i think.

Comment: If I needed to write one for each list then yes that would be rough.  I'd like to write it once and have it monitor all list data.

Comment: I googled a bit for ya and found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243406/attach-eventreceiver-to-all-lists-of-a-sharepoint-site but I don't recommend it. What underlying businessrequirement do you have?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a term store and make it not available for tagging (I've done this with curse words or slang), so that it could not be used. Also, if you control the managed metadata that can be entered in metadata fields, then you could exclude this term store there as well. Another thing you may want to do is make these words "noise words" so that search will ignore these words.

Other than doing these things to limit the use of the words, as well as educating by policy, you can look at using some sort of content evaluator, these can be quite costly, though, and work by looking either for specific words or patterns.